# How to read this piece of code step by step?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def func(num):
    if num==1:
        return 1
    num=num-1
    print(num)
    z=func(num)*num
    print(num)
    return z
func(6)
```

I am a beginner in python study and it's hard for me to read recursive code like this.
Could you guys introduce the right step of reading this piece of code for me?
I am also a little puzzled that why the two sets of output are in contrary order.
Thanks.

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Answer (score 2):

Try using this site to visualize your python code in a step-by-step manner:

[Python visualisation tool](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

This site helped me as a beginner to understand and debug my code.